# How to catch a subclass of DRF ValidationError?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a custom error class subclassed from DRF's `ValidationError`.
I can raise it, but I can not catch that error subclass, only `ValidationError`.

```py
from rest_framework import serializers, status

class CustomValidationError(serializers.ValidationError):
    status_code = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
    default_detail = "Something did not go well"
    default_code = "custom_error"


class CustomSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    custom_data = serializers.JSONField()
    
    def validate_custom_data(self, data):
        raise CustomValidationError()

s = CustomSerializer(data={"custom_data": {}})
try: 
    s.is_valid(raise_exception=True) 
except CustomValidationError as exc:
    print("caught custom error")
except serializers.ValidationError as exc:
    print(f"caught default DRF error\n{exc}")

# output is:
# "caught default DRF error" 
# {'custom_data': [ErrorDetail(string='Something did not go well', code='custom_error')]}
```

So the correct exception `default_detail`, `default_code` is captured, but the exception subclass is not being caught.
I feel like I'm missing something very basic here... can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom serizlier that subclasses Serializer and override [`serializers.Serializer.run_validation`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L409-L427) to the following:

```py
def run_validation(self, data=empty):
    """
    We override the default `run_validation`, because the validation
    performed by validators and the `.validate()` method should
    be coerced into an error dictionary with a 'non_fields_error' key.
    """
    (is_empty_value, data) = self.validate_empty_values(data)
    if is_empty_value:
        return data

    value = self.to_internal_value(data)
    try:
        self.run_validators(value)
         value = self.validate(value)
         assert value is not None, '.validate() should return the validated data'
    except DjangoValidationError as exc:
        raise ValidationError(detail=as_serializer_error(exc))
    except ValidationError as exc:
        raise exc.__class__(detail=as_serializer_error(exc))

        return value
```

Credit to [@getup](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4599228/getup8) for showing me the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that `s.is_valid()` just isn't raising your custom error.

If you just do this, you'll get what you expect:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers, status

class CustomValidationError(serializers.ValidationError):
    status_code = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
    default_detail = "Something did not go well"
    default_code = "custom_error"


try:
    raise CustomValidationError()
except CustomValidationError:
    print('yay')
```

Whether that actually helps you, I'm not sure.. DRF's documentation on custom validators is here:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#writing-custom-validators

Comment: Thanks, but `CustomSerializer.validate_custom_data` is already a custom validator.  I updated my example to indicate that the correct exception contents are captures, but I think you're correct - `s.is_valid` only raises `ValidationError`.  I find that unintuitive, bu the behaviour is not documented.

Comment: The question is really, how to get DRF's `Serializer` class to raise the proper exception type?

Comment: I guess a question back to you is why do not want to raise a `ValidationError`? What are you trying to do? DRF's documentation is pretty explicit that that's what should be raised from any custom validation. Also, you can read the code for `is_valid` and `run_validation`: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L212
https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L409 ... basically your custom exception is being caught and turned into a `ValidationError` and your code/detail is passed along to it.

Comment: Actually, `CustomValidationError` is a subclass of `ValidationError`.  This is pretty much in line with DRF examples, since a subclass can include specific information in `default_detail` and `default_code` class variables.  However, you are correct, the DRF code clearly shows that only a `ValidationError` is raised.  TY.

Comment: @getup8 Regarding `...why do not want to raise a ValidationError?`; Think of a team of engineers writing code for several microservices with the requirement that all of them should generate a normalized error response where you want to add additional details to the error message.

From a development perspective, it would be nice if I could just subclass the DRF `ValidationError` and add additional fields to it. This way, each developer is simply responsible for raising the `CustomValidationError` and supply the appropriate value for the required fields. There's no simple way to do this today